# Creation of a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, core-data, uitableview

I am facing following Exceptions while creating the custom cell.

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MasterTableView 0xb612b30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key address.'`

The delegate function i am using is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{

    NSArray *top=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];// on this line program received SIGABRT

    for (id current in top) {
        if ([current isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell=(CustomCell *)current;
            break;
        }
    }

}

// Configure the cell...
cell.name.text=@"name";
cell.address.text=@"Address";

return cell;
}
```

Besides this i have done the following steps:

1. i have given File owner of the `CustomCell.xib` to `MasterTableView.h`
2. i have given outlet of the custom cell to `MasterTableView.h`
3. i have given outlets for the two `UILabel` s to `CustomCell.h`
4. I have given `Cell` as Cell Identifier in IB

I have shared the whole project in Dropbox, available in the below stated link. You can check that one also. I want to know what wrong in it..

[Download link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dy2jusbwldly8px/CoreDataTest2.zip)

Please show me the missing steps..
Thank you in advance.

PS :- I have used CoreData in my project. Without core data this steps have given me the correct desired Output but not in this project. I have checked with default cells. It worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled and ran the code in a sample project, and it worked with no problems at all.  Make sure you have everything connected in Interface builder as previously mentioned!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *top = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id current in top) {
            if ([current isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell=(CustomCell *)current;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cell.title.text = @"Custom cell labels";

    return cell;
}
```

Edit:

You have the IBOutlets connected twice in Interface Builder, I attached images for your reference.  They should not be connected to the File's Owners, remove the connection from File's Owner.

You also will notice the rows are not the right size, you must specify the row size in the table view.

[image]

Comment: I have done that too..i cant figure out what is happening..it should run..somewhere i am missing something for sure//

Comment: Thanks for this confirmation..This helps me a lot..Let me review again the parts in Interface Builder.

Comment: I have used core data.. can that be an issue in MainBundle??just curious to know.

Comment: i have created an outlet from the CustomCell to MasterViewController..so redeclaration of cell will again give another error..

Comment: You know what i have just created a fresh project and completed all the steps i was doing before, and it all come without any exception. Runs like butter.. But what happened to my earlier project?? The only thing differ between the two project is core data. In previous one i have used core data and in this new one i have created from a simple master-detail template..

core data is somewhere assisting the exception..but data is correctly storing and retrieving..

Comment: if you need i can give you the project.Its not a big deal..just let me know how you want to receive it..i mean should i use dropbox or any other means..

Comment: Sorry for replying late..As you have asked i am giving you the link of the project.

Please Check

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dy2jusbwldly8px/CoreDataTest2.zip

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16257/discussion-between-pranjal-bikash-das-and-vikings)

Comment: i have deleted the initializer as you told but the problem remain intact. it is still there..and right after 10-15 seconds of running the app in simulator, xcode crashes..

Comment: @PranjalBikashDas check the edit, that was the problem all along

Answer (score 1):

In your custom cell xib, change cell object type to `Customcell` and FileOwner type to `NSObject`. Then set the outlet from the cell object.

Comment: I have done that the problem still persist and program receiving the same SIGABRT in 
`
 NSArray *top=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
`

Comment: where do you call this method? make a static method in your custom cell class and call it there.

Comment: I have checked all the steps in blank fresh projects and it all worked fine but when i used the core data this line of code gives me SIGABRT

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have set the class of your CustomCell from properties.
[image]